# Dart JS interop for library using jQuery

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I am attempting to use Dart's package:js to create an interop library for JScrollPane, which is wrapped with jQuery.

Here's what I have so far:

```
@JS()
library jscrollpane;

import 'dart:html';

import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS()
@anonymous
abstract class JScrollPaneSettings {
    external factory JScrollPaneSettings({bool showArrows});

    external bool get showArrows;

    external set showArrows(bool value);

}

@JS()
class JScrollPane {
    external JScrollPane(Element element, JScrollPaneSettings settings);
}
```

And here's the error:

```
Not a valid JS object

STACKTRACE:
#0      JsNative.callConstructor (dart:js:1461)
#1      JScrollPane.JScrollPane (package:portal/base/views/scrollbar/jscrollpane.dart_js_interop_patch.dart:13:30)
```

And here's the JS library - http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.jscrollpane.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Element` is from `dart:html` and is not annoted with `@anonymous`, you should use the `dynamic` keyword instead.

```
@JS()
class JScrollPane {
  external JScrollPane(dynamic element, JScrollPaneSettings settings);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Since it is a jQuery plugin, I don't think you can directly access to the JScrollPane, I have never wrap a jQuery plugin, but if you take the example code of the plugin:

```
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
```

You can try to wrap the `$` function

```
@JS('\$')
external jQuery(query);

@JS()
@anonymous
class JScrollPaneElement {
  external jScrollPane();
}

void main() {
  JScrollPaneElement scrollPane = jQuery('.scroll-pane') as JScrollPaneElement;
  scrollPane.jScrollPane();
}
```