# Angular Dart external JS

Tags: javascript, angular, dart

I am building an Angular-Dart site based on a commercial Bootstrap template.

The correct rendering should be like this:

[image]

I used IntelliJ to scaffold a Dart/Angular app and started to modify from there.

I have put related files (CSS/JS/images) of that template into `web/css`, `web/js`, respectively.

HTML used is verbatim copied from the template but I have taken out the CSS, JS reference from `btqun_component.html` and moved into `index.html`.

The output is like this:

[image]

Obviously, the CSS is working, and the header/footer are showing correctly. But the masonry effect is not showing, so I doubt that is related to JS reference.

Can anyone give any hints on this?

Comment: you are not able to use external 3rd party js in angular is that so ?

Comment: I think so as this template uses a lot of external 3rd party JS files to have those fancy effects.

Comment: Please look at this answer on SO how to import third party JS [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45387777/2708210)

Comment: Thanks. It is very strange that I have to use this kind of workaround. Is there a more straightforward method? BTW, I am not using `cli` so there is no such file `angular-cli.json`

Comment: actually this is the official way , what are you using webpack ?

Comment: I am using Angular Dart and IntelliJ

Comment: I'd like to answer but I don't think you're giving the information needed. Is there an error in the JavaScript console? What is it? What specifically is in btqun_component.html? Did you copy that all over?

This may very well be an issue with webpack — btqun_component.html looks like a WebComponent, which webpack could need some special directory structure for — which goes way beyond AngularDart.

Comment: @TaylorR were you able to solve this problem? I'm in your exact same situation

Comment: Providing more code that allows to reproduce might help.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a documentation for the bootstrap template ? I guess you need to execute the javascript they provide to you so you need to add it to your `index.html`, and you probably need to import `bootstrap` and `jquery` too.

If you need to call a javascript function you can do it directly in the `index.html` inside a `script` tag or build a dart wrapper using [package:js](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js)

EDIT: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43402307/dart-js-interop-for-library-using-jquery/43411815#43411815) to call jQuery function from Dart